# How to turn autoplay background video into youtube video on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, youtube, html5-video

I am using the bigvideo.js jquery plugin for a background video no my website.
This obviously does not work on mobile devices. That is why I would like to show a youtube video instead, like on this website: http://www.henrysaiz.com/

Here is my code snippet:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
          var BV = new $.BigVideo();
                BV.init();
                BV.show('video.mp4',{ambient:true});
            }
        });
</script>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I guess you'll have same issue using youtube video, mobile device don't allow autoplay feature for video. This is what is suggested by bigVideo.js plugin author: `Keep in mind that mobile devices do not allow video autoplay. To account for this, use Modernizr to detect for touchscreen devices, then send a large poster image for BigVideo to use instead` http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-ambient-touch.html

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! You are absolutely correct! That is why i included the link of the homepage, where the mobile versi9n offers a youtube video without autoplay, which is exactly what i want. I just do not know how to make a youtube video appear instead of the suggested image. I do not know how to implement the forceAutoplay function. :(